# Accessing a hashtable value within a ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell-2.0

How to access the value of $hash["greetings"] from a scriptblock. In the following code, the scriptblock fails at execution time when accessing the hashtable and the "bye" message never gets displayed.

```
$hash = @{}

$timeoutCallback = @"
    write-host "hello"
    write-host `$hash["greetings"]
    write-host "bye"
    `$timeout.Dispose()
"@

$hash["greetings"] = "Hi"

$timeoutCallback = [scriptblock]::Create($timeoutCallback)
$timeout = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$timeout.Interval = 1000
$timeout.Enabled = $true
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timeout -EventName Elapsed -Action $timeoutCallback
```

Comment: I'm not on powershell 2.0 but on 5.0 executed as `powershell.exe -version 2` and your code works as expected.

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: There is no error message. If I try with powershell.exe -version 2 it doesn't work for me either. I added "Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0;" as well. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Nifaal So, the "Hello" message is written to the console and then nothing else happens?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what is happening.